# How to export multiple JPG with one layer changing using Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Im trying to make a set of certificates and I have each name on a different layer. I want to export each certificate with a deferent name with the template being the same.

Comment: Hi Naveen! Have you tried anything on your own yet that didn't work? Depending on the amount of names you have to do this for, you could do it manually (by turning on / off layers and then saving), or if you have tons of names to do this for you could write an action or script to do this. If you could edit your question to include some of these additional details it will help people answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This can be done by scripting. I dont have time to whip up an example right now but you can use the script in [how-to-do-animation-frame-pngs](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/55807/how-to-do-animation-frame-pngs/55809#55809) as a starting point. It would be quite easy to make it recognize locked layers as nontogglable entities for example.
2. Though it may be easier to use  text variables instead a bunch of layers. See [adding-individual-guest-names-to-a-wedding-invitation-in-illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/57751/adding-individual-guest-names-to-a-wedding-invitation-in-illustrator/) for more info on how to do this. In either case you can toggle layers too with variables so same approach can be used with layers too its jut unnessecery work but there may be some reasons to do this such as having different fonts etc.
3. it is possible to use a action to toggle layer save hide layer move selection upp by one layer. But this would be a bit tedious so I wouldnt use it especially since scripting takes less time with a good scaffold as a startingpoint, but YMMV.

Comment: Tried the 2nd option and it's just what I wanted. thanks @joojaa

Comment: @werlox you should consider accepting the answer if it answers your question. That helps the site work better.

Comment: i did. notification shows saying 'Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score'

Comment: @werlox not upvote, accept is the icon below that has a checkmark. you can allways accept your own questions.

Comment: oh sorry, it's done (:

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is use InDesign. Create a master page with the certificate and a master column just to fit the names in. Create as many pages as names. Auto-flow the names. Your Done. InDesign is great for variable printing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is currently a tool for illustrator to systematically turn on and off a series of layers and export them individually as you envision.

I would suggest duplicating the Artboard as many times as you have different names. Then turn on one name per artboard.

At that point you would be able to export the Artboards as jpgs in a batch.